# How to create Vm in azure using c# rest api by using publish settings file

Tags: azure, c#-4.0, azure-virtual-machine

I need to create multiple vms in azure by using publish settings file in c# rest api. I could find APIs for creating vm by using thumbprint alone not for publish settings file. Please let me know is there any option. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you open up publish settings file, you will notice that it's an XML file and one of the attribute in there is "ManagementCertificate". This is essentially the certificate used for authentication.

What you would need to do is convert this data into byte array (using `Convert.FromBase64String`) and then create an `X509Certificate2` object using that byte array.

Once you get the certificate object, you can read its thumbprint and proceed as you would normally using that thumbprint.